# How do I redirect https:// to https://www on .htacess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ftp, opencart

I am modifying the .htacess. I tried changing https://mydomain.com to https://www.mydomain.com with the code below. Which failed.

```
# REDIRECT HTTPS:// TO HTTPS://WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my___domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my___domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

As a note:

If this helps, to redirect both the IP and the original 3_$ (_">http://my3_$.com) to _">http://www.3__$.com I used these codes in the beginning, which worked.

```
# REDIRECT IP TO WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my___domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# REDIRECT HTTP:// TO HTTP://WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my___domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my___domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am trying to redirect the https:// because after modifying the two above successfully, I was unable to log in, as those were https:// pages.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `http://www.___.com/$1`, use `//www.___.com/$1`.  It will use http or https, whichever was used in the original request.  Currently, you're forcing http, which seems to be the opposite of what you want.

Comment: So if I use //www.___.com/$1 it will automatically pick the correct one (http or https) to use?

Comment: Yes.  Cool little trick, isn't it?  I only learned about it recently, even though I've been doing all sorts of web programming and sysadmin work for ages.  301 redirect Location headers are probably supposed to be complete, absolute URIs, but I'm sure that Apache will figure it out, and if it doesn't, the web browsers certainly will.  Some spambots might not, but no issue there.

Comment: I tried to use that and it didn't work. Opencart rejects it when I use that. Is there an easier manual way?

Comment: You could just have two separate versions, one with `%{HTTPS} =on`, and another with `${HTTPS} !=on`.  Just be sure to make one `https://`, because you were missing the "s" in the example code, as @faa also pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I used this rewrite for redirect from `http` to `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I guess in Your case adding something like this would do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Hmm?